# Utilizar variável recebida via route angular 2 final releasee

Tags: angular

Estou começando a aprender o angular 2 e estou com uma dúvida de como usar variável dentro de um componente (`AppComponent.ts`), recebida via service.
Eu enviei via servisse o id de um cadastro e recebo no componente distinto, tanto é que eu consigo visualizar ela na view através de interpolação {{ }}.
Mas eu gostaria de usar esta variável, que é um objeto, para montar outra variável neste componente, e não estou conseguindo, o valor fica como não definido.
No Componente eu recebo a variável com segue:

```
import.....

    export clas.....{
     id : number;
     aaa : string;

ngOnInit() {

        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.usuariosService.buscarPorId(this.id)
            .subscribe(
                    usuario => {
                    this.usuario = usuario
                  });

    this.aaa = this.usuario['nome'];
    this.log('ngOnInit');
    console.log(this.aaa);
}
```

o valor da variável `aaa` não é atribuída, eu já tentei de diversas formas, já procurei na net, mas não consigo utilizar o que recebo pelo `route` dentro do arquivo TS, somente dentro do HTML.

Comment: Acredito que seja this.usuario.nome se o nome dentro do objeto for publico caso seja private crie um método getter publico ficando this.usuario.getNome(), coloca o codigo do serviço e esse objeto usuário quais são suas propriedades/metodos?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O problema esta relacionado a chamada http ser assíncrona, e quando trecho :

```
this.aaa = this.usuario['nome'];
```

é executado, ainda não teve retorno do servidor. Para o correto funcionamento voce deve trabalhar com Observer ou Promise, segue um exemplo, utilizando promise:

```
this.http.get('http://test.com/api/user') .map(res => res.json()).toPromise().then((result) => {
                this.usuario = usuario;
                this.aaa = this.usuario['nome'];
            }).catch(() => {
               console.log('Error')
            });
```